# Button "Call me back" on mobile view of web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm asking me if there is any way to get the cell phone number of the website when visitors are on mobile ?
Is there a way in js by asking some navigator properties or anything else ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that is privacy breach

Comment: You cannot get it directly from the device. All you can do is present an input box for someone to willingly give you their phone number.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way you can get a phone number of a device. It's private information.

Comment: i've seen a button which activate a call to my phone on the web site of my insurance how can they do that ?

Comment: You sure it was activating a call to your phone? Probably, you were calling them...

Comment: Sure that after pushing it my phone had effectively ringed from a number, it was not my phone which emit the call.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Give us a link to your insurance company. We'll figure it out.

Comment: [link]https://m.gmf.fr/ go to "nous contacter" -> "être rappelé" it's this last link which initiate the call me back process

Comment: I went through the process and it seems like it is asking for your phone number on [this page](https://m-services.gmf.fr/call-back?pgCB=imm1).

Comment: I'm going to the link with my smartphone and don't had to enter my number to be recalled by my insurance.